# Cribbage run scoring

Tags: cribbage

During the show if you have a 5,6,7,8 in hand and the start card is a 9, do you score 4 for the initial run plus an additional 5 for the the five card run? Would the total score for that hand be 13?

Answer (score 3):

No, you only score runs once with the longest length so you would only score 5 plus you would score 4 more for your 15's.  So the score of the hand would be 9.